# Beta test through Testflight to people without without apple ID account

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testflight, apple-id

I was wondering if it is possible to add testers without apple account through TestFlight. I mean with just a gmail or hotmail account, because just a few of my testers have apple ID. If not is there any way to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your testers must have an Apple ID since without one they cannot download and install the TestFlight app from the App Store, but you don't need to know what it is.

You can add any email address as an external TestFlight tester.  The email doesn't have to be an Apple ID.

The tester will receive an email with an invitation code that they redeem inside the TestFlight app. Once they redeem the code your test versions will be associated with the AppleID they are using with the App Store.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I invite someone without via gmail He receives this :              Dear XX,

XXXXX invited you to join their team in App Store Connect. To get started, activate your account and sign in with your Apple ID. If you don’t have an Apple ID, follow the activation link to create one.

If you have any questions, contact us.

Best regards,
The App Store Team

Comment: Is their iphone id for app store taken as apple id ?

Comment: That isn't an external TestFlight invitation. You are inviting them to join your development team. You (probably) don't want to do that.  You need to add them as a tester in App Store Connect.  Apple will need to review your build before it is available to external testers.